# Event reciever (itemadded) sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, visual-studio, object-model, event-receivers, item

is there a way where we can get the link(editform.aspx) of item just added to the list-- in the itemadded method of the event receiver  (Share Point object model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should give you the Url to the edit form:

```
string editUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}?ID={2}", properties.WebUrl, properties.List.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM].Url,properties.ListItemId);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the [SPListItem.URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_members.aspx) property of the item in the itemadded event receiver. The URL property gets the site-relative URL of the item.

Hope I have understood your question correctly.